# Not able to change the width of a bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table which is something like this

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td align="center" style="width:30%"><input type="text"
      class="form-control" id="tag" name="tag"
      placeholder="Enter Tag For The Change" maxlength='140'
            > <input type="hidden"
      class="form-control" id="userEmail" name="userEmail"
      placeholder="Enter Tag For a Change" maxlength='140'></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Despite setting the width of the column to 30% the table still expands across the entire screen 
I also have this CSS set for the table

```html
table {
 table-layout: fixed;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: It will take full width unless you add another `<td>` inside `<tr>`. you can give width to `<table>` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your table to be *smaller* and not take up the entire screen, then you have your inline style in the wrong place.

Instead of setting the width for the `<td>`, set the width for the `<table>`.

This should solve your problem:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" style="width: 30%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" name="tag" placeholder="Enter Tag For The Change" maxlength='140' /> 
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" placeholder="Enter Tag For a Change" maxlength='140'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/M1B2K3Chsi) of this in action.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the table for layout rather than data. I recommend using the grid system like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" name="tag" placeholder="Enter Tag For The Change" maxlength="140"> <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" placeholder="Enter Tag For a Change" maxlength="140">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you must use the table, you can override its width:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" style="width:30% !important;">
```